# jQuery fadeOut on dynamically creative div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've wrote something that allows me to dynamically create div's but I'm having a few issues making it fade out using Jquery. The div is currently appearing but not fading away.

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
   <script>
   socket.on('hello', function (answer) {
        console.log('hello?: ' + answer);
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute("id", "#fade");
        div.style.margin = Math.floor((Math.random() * 400) + 1) + "px";
        div.style.width = "100px";
        div.style.height = "100px";
        div.style.background = "red";
        div.style.color = "white";
        div.innerHTML = "Hello";
        document.body.appendChild(div); 
        $("#fade").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow"); //Fadeout
    });
   </script>

   <body>
   </body>
```

Comment: Try wrapping this in a $(document).ready(function(){   }); perhaps?

Comment: @neilsimp1 Just did that, still nothing. http://puu.sh/ir3NO/aba6e537c8.png The div appears but no fade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vanilla DOM functions don't use a # sign for IDs.  Change

```
div.setAttribute("id", "#fade");
```

To

```
div.setAttribute("id", "fade");
```

Answer (score 4):

You have the ID wrong, you're setting it to `#fade`, not just `fade`, you don't add the hash when setting it, but why not use jQuery

```
socket.on('hello', function (answer) {

    $('<div />', {
        id  : 'fade',
        css : {
            margin     : Math.floor((Math.random() * 400) + 1),
            width      : 100,
            height     : 100,
            background : 'red',
            color      : 'white'
        },
        html : 'Hello'
    }).delay(3000).fadeOut('slow').appendTo('body');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3z0m2ppc/)